# Laravel eloquent duplicating data when using create method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple array thats returned when executing:

`$this->forecast($value->id,$value->db_connection)`

when I call the `$reports::create($data)` it duplicates each row, i have added some logic to print out $data within the foreach and it never returns duplicates, when printing the $result object it has 2 entries.

any idea where i am going wrong?

```
 public function store() // function to store report data in db
{
    $reports = new Reports;

    $companyData = new ClientSettings;
    $settings = $companyData::all();

    foreach ($settings as $value) {

        $data = $this->forecast($value->id,$value->db_connection);
        $result = $reports::create($data);

    }
    echo "Forecast generated";   
}
```

Comment: Replace `$reports::create` with `Reports::create`

Comment: Yes, as mentioned by @mcklayin, this probably not the code you are using. Would you please provide the code, and and the forecast function?

Comment: hi the forecast function is too big to show, if it helps i have dumped the $result object and the `$data` is showing in attributes & orginal

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store() // function to store report data in db
{
    $reports = new Reports;

    $companyData = new ClientSettings;
    $settings = $companyData::all();

    foreach ($settings as $value) {

        $data = $this->forecast($value->id,$value->db_connection);
        $result = Reports::create($data);

    }
    echo "Forecast generated";   
}
```